# WebRTC DataChannel not according to specs?

Tags: javascript, html, real-time, webrtc

Are the browsers mainly Nightly and Canary using the SCTP streams for datachannel ?
Atleast in http://simpl.info/rtcdatachannel/ I can't see SCTP streams and 
even http://mozilla.github.com/webrtc-landing/data_test.html is not working ? Did they change anything lately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox uses **SCTP** streams and Chrome **RTP**. *This is the main interoperability issue in these days.*

You can find some working text-chat/file-sharing demos [here](https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/).